# Can Optional be used to as alternative to catch ConversionException

Tags: java, monads, option-type

How to refactor the following code of reading properties file, so that it returns int, double or String depending on the read value?

```
    public static <T> T readFromConfig(String keyName) {
    PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
    String propertiesFilePath = "src/main/resources/application.properties";
    try {
        config.load(propertiesFilePath);
        try {
            Integer value = config.getInt(keyName);
            return (T) value;
        } catch (ConversionException notInteger) {
            try {
                Double value = config.getDouble(keyName);
                return (T) value;
            } catch (ConversionException notDouble) {
                return (T) config.getString(keyName);
            }
        }
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        logger.warn("Could not parse " + propertiesFilePath);
        return (T) "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how an `Optional` can be used here to optimize the code. IMHO you have to try different conversions if you don't know which datatype is given within the properties. I think the code is easy to understand and does not see the ultimate need for optimization here.

Comment: OK, so Optional can catch only NPE, right?

Comment: Yes, an `Optional` is used to prevent returning `null`. Null checks and/or NPEs can be reduced though.

Comment: Note that this is also a bit strange use of PropertiesConfiguration. You should know in advance which type the property should have, and try to fetch only that type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I can suggest you also this is a clear violation of Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) as it tries to convert to three different types which should be avoided for cleaner code :

```
public static Optional<Object> readFromConfig(String keyName) {
    PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
    String propertiesFilePath = "src/main/resources/opf.properties";
    try {
        config.load(propertiesFilePath);

        return Stream.<Supplier<Optional>>of(
                () -> Optional.of(config.getInt(keyName)),
                () -> Optional.of(config.getDouble(keyName)),
                () -> Optional.of(config.getString(keyName)))
                .map(Supplier::get)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .findFirst();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is not really an improvement.

Comment: @GhostCat from clean code perspective is an improvement otherwise no. this code has high cyclomatic complexity (3 level inner try catch) whereas mine not

Comment: But well, i get your point. Got my vote for that. Feel free to comment on my answer ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for that :) . sure, apart from cyclomatic complexity, the stream in my example has got O(n) if you mean time complexity of that and as n here is 3 which is a small amount could be ignore comparing to the readability and reducing cyclomatic factor. hope I described it clearly.

Comment: Yeah, well. Stream and "performance" I often cringe. A ton of things happen in the background when you call that such little methods like of(). Out of curiosity: when getInt() would throw ... that results in the Optional.of() getting null? Wouldnt that just throw up right there? Without a try/catch?

Comment: @GhostCat yes,you are right. Optional.of()  is not getting null as the apache api throws an exception instead of returning null. my suggestion was an attempt to transform the author's api into an optional friendly one, but yes it's not a real improvement.

Answer (score 1):

As the author figured himself: `Optional<>` isn't an option here, because, as the other answer shows: it would result in returning `Optional<Object>` which gives even *less* type information.

But honestly, from a clean code perspective, even the idea of

```
public static <T> T readFromConfig(String keyName) {
```

is kinda *flawed*. What does that method buy? **Nothing**. Because the caller says: I expect an Integer to come back, but you push back a Double or even String. You see, the compiler gets told "the method should return Integer, or Double, ...", and then it sees: "yes, possible". But that is totally decoupled from what happens at runtime.

If you go:

```
Integer intVal = readFromConfig("keyPointingToDoubleValue");
```

the compiler will not complain. Because it sees: you *want* an Integer; and hey, the method *can* return an Integer.

At runtime? When the value is retrieved, and isn't an Integer, a Double or String is returned. No idea what will happen here (class cast exception, or maybe some stack violation). But it should *not* work at runtime.

So, the **real** solution goes like this:

Either you have multiple methods, such as:

```
public static Integer readIntegerFromConfig(String keyName) throws SomeException ...
public static Integer readIntegerFromConfig(String keyName, Integer Default) throws SomeException ...
```

Or maybe:

```
public static Object readFromConfig(String keyName) {
```

or

```
public static <T> T readFromConfig(String keyName, T default)
```

In other words: you want an API that allows users of it to **really** say what they want, and always give them what they want. Or you totally avoid distinct types on that level, and return Strings, and have the client code make conversions.

Your current approach, as said: buys you nothing, at the cost of a misleading, complicated API.

Comment: I agree with you completely, as you described there is no easy workaround for a better API in this purpose. and again From clean code perspective it's also worth to mention that, each method should be doing only one logic but the author tries to do 3 different things which violates clean code principals. Also for clear description your answer also deserves an up-vote :)

Answer (score 0):

So, that's the end of deiscussion.
The answer for question "Can Optional be used to as alternative to catch ConversionException?" is **NO**